# AWS Confused Deputy - is "external id" really just a "password"?

Tags: security, amazon-web-services, passwords

Amazon Web Services describes the Confused Deputy Problem and prescribes use of "external ID" as the solution.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_create_for-user_externalid.html
http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/security/blog/tag/Confused+Deputy

The Confused Deputy Problem is also described here:
http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~KeyKOS/ConfusedDeputy.html
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confused_deputy_problem

Amongst all the fancy talk however, it appears that ultimately "external ID" is just a password. Am I understanding this right or wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, the External ID used with IAM Third-Party Roles is a glorified password.

I'll be using the following terms here:

- ServiceA - Third-party service of AWS accounts
- User1 - Original well-intentioned user of ServiceA
- User2 - Devious user of ServiceA trying to get access to User1's AWS account

IAM Roles are a way to ensure that only ServiceA can use User1's IAM Role. User1's IAM Role is tied to ServiceA's AWS account. But the extra External ID is needed to ensure that ServiceA is only acting for User1. Without the External ID, User2 could trick ServiceA into acting for User2.

If User2 guessed User1's IAM Role ARN and can tell ServiceA which External ID to use, then User2 could trick ServiceA into acting on it's behalf in User1's AWS account.

So instead, ServiceA should always dictate the values of the External IDs. This limits the ability of User2 to spoof itself as User1 in the eyes of ServiceA.

Comment: Man they sure like to make it hard to understand don't they.  AWS could have said "External ID, it's similar to a password - make sure you use it", instead there's a thousand words and "confused deputies" to get confused about.

Comment: Where do I get the external ID to share with another account to get a role on another account to switch and access resources on that account?

Comment: As the service provider executing `sts:AssumeRole`, you would generate the External ID value yourself. It can be a GUID, or some other value.

Comment: How do one use external id while switching role in GUI. @ManjitKumar where you able to figure out how to generate external id.

Comment: @Sar009 you can't enter one in the GUI, you will have to use AWS CLI to access that account

Comment: Is it possible for user2 to guess user1's IAM Role ARN? ARN should have aws account id as well right?

Comment: Yes, it will have the AWS account ID, but that's only a 12-digit number, and it's not secure. How you define "guess" is up to you: perhaps you actually know someone else's AWS account ID, perhaps you write a program to brute-force try all 12-digit numbers (not hard).

Comment: Also, user2 may not be looking for *your* ARN specifically, but instead, *any* user1 of ServiceA. So without the external ID, they could control any other user of ServiceA where they can guess a valid ARN.

Comment: Another example: by the very process of establishing a valid IAM third-party role, user2 knows ServiceA's AWS account ID. Now, if user2 suspects that ServiceA uses another third-party service ServiceB, then they can guess ServiceA's IAM third-party role ARN for ServiceB.